# Why is there a hole to nowhere bored in my foundation? Better to seal it or leave it be?

Tags: hvac, concrete, basement, foundation, vent

Continuation of [Air exchanger stale exhaust too restrictive? Some other issue?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/287605/air-exchanger-stale-exhaust-too-restrictive-some-other-issue) where I had incorrectly identified this bizarre vent as my passive air exchanger's stale air outlet:

[image: Vent Cover]

I finally opened and scoped it. Behind the plate is a 2¾" ⌀ bored hole through the foundation wall which ends at pink batten insulation inside the foundation wall.

[image: Vent cover open]

[image: Pink batten within foundation]

[image: Small gap between wall and batten]

The basement was remodeled and a bedroom was added on the other side of this wall, I'd guess within the last 15 years or so. If relevant, the remodeled room has an in-wall ductless HVAC return (but not in this wall).

I measured the airflow from this opening with the cover in place (zero) and removed ~118 ft/min out, which is close to the exchanger inflow (of 138 ft/min).

There has been electric furnace and thermopump in this house for at least 26 years, but this could have reasonably been a heating oil refill pipe - it's located conveniently from the road for that, and it's about 2 feet from the ground.

I'm in Québec, Canada.

**Questions**

Why would it have been covered up *in this way*, rather than sealed and stuffed with pink insulation or expanding foam?

Is it better to seal it off, leave it alone or replace that bespoke steel plate with a proper cover?

Is there some advantage to venting behind the vapor barrier? There aren't any others, but the person who did this did extra work to make this cover, instead of just sealing it.

Comment: Usually an oil tank has a fill pipe and a slightly smaller vent pipe beside it.  Seems a lot of air flow with insulation on the inside.  For that much air flow, there should be an inlet somewhere.

Comment: Good point! There is no adjacent (or far away) vent hole. Also, my central blower runs constantly, and I do have an air exchanger, which had a blocked outflow, which I largely fixed today (blew it out with a shop vac).

Comment: A well insulated wall should have very limited air flow(if any).  Insulation does good when it traps air between two surfaces.  It is common to keep insulation/wall construction away from cement by a inch or two, but for that air flow there should be a leak or an inlet to let air(cold in Quebec winter) in.  Might be a badly sealed sill plate/end joist.